# nodemon retriggers server after file write

Tags: node.js, nodemon

My `npm` run script is following:
`"start": "nodemon ./server.js --ignore './config.json'",`

But still, this line of code (executed in root directory) is causing `nodemon` to constantly re-triggers server:

`fs.writeFileSync('./config.json', fs.readFileSync(configInfo.path), { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'w' });`

I tried to add `ignore` in `nodemonConfig` section in `package.json`, as well in separate file, with no expected result.

Does anyone of you experienced similar issue?

Comment: in your code did you using config.json file

Comment: No, it's only created/overwritted at startup